# How do I loop through JSON array

Tags: php, json, codeigniter

How do I traverse and display the names in the following JSON using CodeIgniter?

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Search extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {       

        $json = '[{"name": "John Doe",
                 "address": "115 Dell Avenue, Somewhere",
                 "tel": "999-3000",
                 "occupation" : "Clerk"},
                 {"name": "Jane Doe",
                 "address": "19 Some Road, Somecity",
                 "tel": "332-3449",
                 "occupation": "Student"}]';


        for (int $i = 0; $i < $json.length; $i++){
            ???
        }
        //$obj = json_decode($json);        
        //$this->load->view('search_page');
    }
}

/* End of file search.php */
/* Location: ./application/controllers/search.php */
```

Comment: $json is not a json object its a string.

Comment: +1 so I should use json_decode($json) first?

Comment: Uncomment the line that says json_decode and just loop through the array that it returns. (and this has nothing to do with CodeIgniter)

Comment: +1 $arr = json_decode($json, true); ?

Comment: actually your json string represents an array of objects and not an object itself

Answer (score 62, accepted):

1) `$json` is a string you need to decode it first.

```
$json = json_decode($json);
```

2)  you need to loop through the object and get its members

```
foreach($json as $obj){
   echo $obj->name;
   .....

}
```

Answer (score 6):

another example:

```
  <?php

  //lets make up some data:
  $udata['user'] = "mitch";
  $udata['date'] = "2006-10-19";
  $udata['accnt'] = "EDGERS";
  $udata['data'] = $udata; //array inside
  var_dump($udata); //show what we made

  //lets put that in a file
  $json = file_get_contents('file.json');
  $data = json_decode($json);
  $data[] = $udata;
  file_put_contents('file.json', json_encode($data));

  //lets get our json data
  $json = file_get_contents('file.json');
  $data = json_decode($json);
  foreach ($data as $obj) {
        var_dump($obj->user);
  }
```