# How can I loop through a JSON Object in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have a variable `$arr` in PHP. It has the following data inside it.

This is my PHP Code.

```
    $data = array(
        'Request' => 'StockStatus',
        'merchant_id' => 'shipm8',
        'hash' => '09335f393d4155d9334ed61385712999'
        );

    $url = 'https://ship2you.com/ship2you/';

    $ch = curl_init($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    $arr = json_decode($result, true);

    foreach ($arr as $value) {
        echo $value['packagename'];
    }
```

[image]

I want to loop through it. How can I achieve it? I tried using foreach but it gives me error. Thanks in advance.

Comment: show how did you use foreach ?

Comment: Also post the exact error message.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I loop through JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290798/how-do-i-loop-through-json-object)

Comment: @Anant I have pasted my php code.

Comment: Come on, post the code! Now you added a snippet, but still not the foreach you mentioned...

Comment: Updated my question @GolezTrol

Comment: tried `echo $value->packagename;` or  `echo $value->{'packagename'};` ?

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I tried using echo $value->packagename but it says Message: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: yes that's right (first time on PHP?): replace `echo $value['packagename'];` with `echo $value->packagename;` or `echo $value->{'packagename'};`.

Comment: @SebastianBrosch I tried both. It says Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: `var_dump($arr);`? `foreach ($arr as $value) {echo $value->packagename;}`!!!

Comment: @SebastianBrosch var_dump gives me string(266981).

Comment: I have given the complete curl request. Can you check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to decode your `CURL output string`  twice:-

```
$arr = json_decode(json_decode($result, true),true);

foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($value['packagename']);
}
```

Note:-  @Xatenev  mentioned the correct thing:-

The json has escaped quotes. When a json with escaped quotes is passed to `json_decode()` it only removes all the escaped sequences. When calling `json_decode()` again, it decodes it correctly

Comment: Why do i have to do it twice?

Comment: @AliZia  It seems that double-encoded or you can say nested encoded string comes from `CURL` request

Comment: I wish my API Provider would have mentioned it. Thankyou so much.

Comment: @Anant @AliZia **The json has escaped quotes**. When a json with escaped quotes is passed to `json_decode()` it only removes all the escaped sequences. When calling `json_decode()` again, it decodes it correctly.

Comment: @AliZia   glad to help you. Cheers :):)

Answer (score 1):

```
json_decode($json, true);
```

If the second parameter is true, it will return array. In case it is not what you are looking for, please show the code you have.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, 443);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

$arr = json_decode($result);



foreach ($arr as $arr_item) {
   echo $arr_item->user_id;
}
```