# Create a List of Values from a JSON Object in PHP

Tags: php, json

How can I convert the following JSON object array into an ordered list of values using PHP?

JSON Object

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => {#226 ▼
    +"sum(hour0)": "2098571"
    +"sum(hour1)": "1316168"
    +"sum(hour2)": "643316"
    +"sum(hour3)": "210643"
    +"sum(hour4)": "97135"
    +"sum(hour5)": "25334"
    +"sum(hour6)": "20451"
    +"sum(hour7)": "20639"
    +"sum(hour8)": "20382"
    +"sum(hour9)": "16966"
    +"sum(hour10)": "25301"
    +"sum(hour11)": "17352"
    +"sum(hour12)": "23883"
    +"sum(hour13)": "425294"
    +"sum(hour14)": "3776592"
    +"sum(hour15)": "5292751"
    +"sum(hour16)": "5945308"
    +"sum(hour17)": "952250"
    +"sum(hour18)": "0"
    +"sum(hour19)": "0"
    +"sum(hour20)": "0"
    +"sum(hour21)": "0"
    +"sum(hour22)": "0"
    +"sum(hour23)": "0"
  }
]
```

Desired Output

```
2098571,1315168,643316,210643,...
```

Comment: So far, I've only used: json_encode($object). It converts the object to a string but I'm still not sure how to isolate the values efficiently.

Comment: Why not string operations then ?

Comment: @SulthanAllaudeen Payden offered that solution and it worked. Great minds think alike!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can cast the inner object to an array and implode that.

```
$string = implode(',', (array) $object[0]);
```

In general, casting objects to arrays and vice versa isn't always a good idea. But in this case if you don't care about the keys and just need the values, it should work consistently.

Answer (score 1):

From here: [How do I loop through JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290798/how-do-i-loop-through-json-object)

[You can `foreach` through an Object in PHP.](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
<?php
    $objectJSON = JSON OBJECT;
    $string = '';
    foreach ($objectJSON[0] as $key => $value)
        {
            $values[] = $value;
        }
    $string = implode(",", $values);
?>
```

`$string` ends up being what you need.