# how to store my second image data like first image data using store procedure

Tags: php, arrays, json, stored-procedures

How to merge two json data and then update in one mysqli record using store procedure..

Here two json data has been merge in one record using store procedure.

how to store my second image data like first image data using store procedure?

[image: Image No 1]

[image: Image No 2]

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: how to store my second number image data like first image data using store procedure?

Answer (score -1):

I don't understand what do you want exactly but i think this is solution or help you.

You can convert json to array after this merge array if you want after finish return it to json.

```
// convert object json to array PHP 
$phpArray = json_decode($json); 

// loop on query store    

// convert array php to Json Object
$json = json_encode($phpArray);
```

I hope the solution help you.

read this [How do I loop through JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16290798/how-do-i-loop-through-json-object)